# Scripting the Nuget Package Console inside Visual Studio 2012

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2012, nuget-package

We are using custom Nuget packages in our developments.
These package install commands that are launched with different parameters across the different projects of a solution.
Manually, in the Console Package Manager, the processus is as follow:

```
PM> ==> Select default Project1 in the ComboBox  
PM> Run Command1 ParamA1 ParamB1 ...  
PM> ==> Select default Project1 in the ComboBox  
PM> Run Command2 ParamA2 ParamB2 ...  
Etc
```

for each project.

As these custom packages are a work in progress, they are updated frequently and we must rerun all these commands with each new version.

This manual process is tedious and error prone.

I'd like to script this process.
I know how to create a PowerShell script to issue the commands, but what I don't know is how to switch between the different projects

```
Script.ps1
# Select Project1 ??
Command1 ParamA1 ParamB1 ...
# Select Project2 ??
Command2 ParamA2 ParamB2 ...
....
```

Thanks in advance for you help.
Philippe

Comment: What kind of commands are you running? Are they nuget cmdlets or others?

Comment: That's nuget commands. My problem is really to select the right project

Answer (score 0):

Without the specific commands, this is the best I can do:

Most of the nuget commands take a `-ProjectName` parameter allowing you to specify which one to use:

```
Install-Package -ProjectName MyProject.UnitTests -Id NUnit
```

These commands also have -Project as ValueFromPipeline and ValueFromPipelineProperty, so the following works:

```
Get-Project -All | Install-Package -Id NUnit
```

You can also filter it:

```
Get-Project -All | 
    Where { $_.ProjectName -imatch "Test" } | 
    Install-Package -Id NUnit
```

Or if you want to be even more complex:

```
Get-Project -All | 
    Foreach-Object { 
        if (($_.Type -imatch "C#") -and ($_.ProjectName -imatch "Test")) { 
            Install-Package -Id NUnit -ProjectName $_.Project 
        } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. But it assumes my commands support the -ProjectName switch, which is not the case... I am still looking for a way to change programmatically the default project in the PM console.